# Only keep tags of a Git history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo

Let’s say I have the following Git history:

```
* (develop) commit I
|
* (master) [v1.1] commit H
|
* commit G
|
* [v1.0] commit F
|
* commit E
|
| * (feature-A) commit D 
|/
* [v0.1] commit C
|
* commit B
|
* commit A
|
* Initial commit
```

I need to push in another remote (either within the same local repo, or in another local repo) a truncated version with only the tags from the original repo. Like the following:

```
* [v1.1] commit H’
|
* [v1.0] commit F’
```

As you can see, I need:

- the branches `feature-A` & `develop` to be deleted

  - then, commits `commit D`, and `commit I` are deleted
- the `commit H’` to be a squash of the commits `commit G`, and `commit H`
- the `commit F’` to be a squash of the commits `commit E`, and `commit F`
- the tag `v0.1` to not appear in the resulting tree
- to rewrite the name & email authors in the resulting tree

I’ve read that [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) could help, but I could’t figure out how to use it.

The goal is to push the code to a public repository (to match a requirement where my team is asked to open source the project), but we want to hide some private data like the names of the developers and internal URLs and such.

Comment: Simplest would be to just checkout the first tag, copy sources to a new folder,. init and commit and then rinse and repeat for the other tags.

Comment: @fredrik well, that’s what we were about to do, but I wanted a more automated way of doing. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: That can be completely automated with a shell script (or python).